# Backbone model fetch error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have a Rails3 server where I administrate the users. When I do login in my backbone client app, I connect to the server doing a model.fetch operation. How can I manage correctly when the login is no correct? I mean when the user's name and the password don't match with the database in the Rails server. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.model.fetch({
    success: function (model, response) {
        //TODO: Success
        //Your response JSON object can also have some authentication status 
    },
    error: function (model, response) {
        //TODO: error
    }
});
```